# How to display context and hook names in the React DevTools profiler?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-devtools

I have a React component that consumes multiple contexts and uses multiple hooks, when I profile it and try to find out why it re-renders, The devtools tell me it re-rendered because "Context changed" or "Hook 4 changed", this isn't very insightful and doesn't help me determine which context exactly caused the re-render.

I want it to display the name of the specific context or hook that changed, "useTheme changed" for example.

I already have "Always parse hook names from source" enabled in the settings, it didn't help.

Comment: Hooks are called in the order they are declared, "hook 4" would be the 4th hook in the component.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, but the real problem here is consuming context, you won't be able to know which context caused the re-render

Comment: Apply some debugging steps then. Have you tried narrowing the scope of the code you are rendering to narrow the scope of the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese Don't think I can do that, the component needs all the contexts it's currently consuming to function properly, omitting one will break it.